# how to integrate single sign on from disqus with django allauth

Tags: django, disqus, django-allauth

I am using [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for my django project with social login and at the same time I am using [Disqus](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-integrating-single-sign-on) as my commenting system for my site.

I want to know, how to use the single sign on function from Disqus with allauth?

Comment: hello, anyone with any idea to do this?
thanks

Comment: Wouldn't DisQus recognize you're signed in because of the cookie that the authentication places? Try signing in with facebook, then try commenting as a Facebook user, it should pick up that you're signed in.

Comment: how about the user is not sign in from facebook but signed in by generic account from my site?

Comment: There should be a cookie tool that can help handle that. Have you checked the documentation for it?

Answer (score 2):

Disqus has a guide at:
http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-integrating-single-sign-on

*"Access to Single Sign-On (SSO) is currently available as a free add-on for your Disqus account. Please contact our support team via this contact form and ask them to enable it for your account."*

*"Single sign-on (SSO) allows users to sign into a site and fully use Disqus Comments without again authenticating with Disqus. SSO will create a site-specific user profile on Disqus so as not to clash with existing users of Disqus."**

Disqus itself is not a SSO provider.  But if your users authenticate to your site, they can access disqus without an additional login.

Answer (score 0):

I recently pushed a pull request to the `django-allauth` project adding Disqus provider, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/pull/2014). You can wait the PR to be accepted or check the changes and include them in your project.